# Compare two columns in excel, and copy the difference at the bottom of the second

Tags: excel, vba

In the image, am not interested in the results at the red columns, just want to know how to compare two columns (yellow color), the first column A varies his data, and second column D register all the "history" in column A and this create a "list" or a registry, but I can't resolve how to move or change that columns (A and D) to use it in other columns, for example in J an K.

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim a, i As Long, ii As Long, x As Range
With Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    a = .Value: ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1) * 2, 1 To 3)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = 1
        For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
            If a(i, 4) <> "" Then .Item(a(i, 4)) = Empty
        Next
        For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
            If Not .exists(a(i, 1)) Then
                If x Is Nothing Then
                    Set x = Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 3)
                Else
                    Set x = Union(x, Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 3))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
        x.Copy Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)(2)
        Set x = Nothing
    Else
        MsgBox "No new item"
    End If
    End With 
 End Sub
```

Comment: don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: Time ago someone edited my post because I include some "unnecessary" words like "please", "thanks for your time"... kind words that wasn't necessary. I know that saying this code was taken from other and a lot of pepole are going to see this bad because the code is not my work, I don't have any degree on computers, am a civil engineer just trying to figure out this to make my work easier... am sorry for all the ones that I annoy, it's not my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code do the same as the original code but it can be configured to different columns to compare and copy his differences at the bottom of the second column:

```
    Option Explicit

Function LastRowInColumn(ByVal column As String) As Long
    With Application.ActiveSheet
        LastRowInColumn = .Cells(.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Sub test()
    ' Nombre de las columnas x y y
    Dim xCol As String, yCol As String
    ' Número de elementos en las columnas x y y
    Dim x, y, i As Long
    ' Rango de valores para las columnas x y y
    Dim xRng, yRng As Range
    ' Valor de la celda en el rango de columnas x y y
    Dim xCell, yCell As Range

    ' Definir columnas a utilizar
xCol = "Q"
yCol = "O"

' Obtener el número de elementos de dichas columnas
x = LastRowInColumn(xCol)
y = LastRowInColumn(yCol)

' Salvar en un rango los elementos de las columnas
Set xRng = Worksheets(1).Range(xCol & 1 & ":" & xCol & x)
Set yRng = Worksheets(1).Range(yCol & 1 & ":" & yCol & y)

' Colección para almacenar nuevos elementos a agregar en columna y
Dim newItems As New Collection

' Iterar entre ambas columnas para ver cual valor es nuevo y debe ser agregado
For Each xCell In xRng
    For Each yCell In yRng
        If StrComp(xCell.Text, yCell.Text) = 0 Then
            GoTo ContinueLoop
        End If
    Next

    newItems.Add (xCell.Text)
 ContinueLoop:
    Next

' Agregar valores nuevos a columna y
For i = 1 To newItems.Count
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, yCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(N, yCol).Value = newItems.Item(i)
Next i


End Sub
```

My thanks to @AlexandroSifuentes for his help!